# Authorization of alfresco user while calling webscript inside IFrame

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I'm developping a component to easily edit associations in document properties pages.
The visual part of the component is an IFRAME showing the myspaces webscript.
I'm having difficulties to transfer user authentication to the content of the IFRAME. The session is lost, so the browser ask for a new BasicAuthentication. 
I can transfer the ticket using the alf_ticket url parameter, but it is not reused for other urls produced by the webscript.

How could I transfer the Alfresco authentication to the webscript included in the IFRAME ?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var self = this;
    var ticket;
    var xmlHttpReq = false;
    // Mozilla/Safari
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        self.xmlHttpReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    // IE
    else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        self.xmlHttpReq = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    self.xmlHttpReq.open("GET", "http://blrkec335927d:8080/alfresco/wcservice/api/login?u=admin&pw=admin", true);
    self.xmlHttpReq.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'json');
    self.xmlHttpReq.setRequestHeader('X-Alfresco-Remote-User', 'admin');
    xmlHttpReq.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
        alert(xmlHttpReq.status);
            if (xmlHttpReq.readyState == 4 && xmlHttpReq.status == 200)
            {
                var xml = xmlHttpReq.responseXML;
            var getticket = xml.getElementsByTagName("ticket");
            ticket = getticket[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
                  var url1 = "http://blrkec335927d:8080/alfresco/wcservice/ui/myspaces?f=0&p=%2FCompany%20Home&alf_ticket="+ticket;
                var aa='<iframe bgcolor="#edf6fc" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder=0 src="'+url1+'" />';
                document.getElementById('uploaddoc').innerHTML = aa; 
            }
        }
    self.xmlHttpReq.send();

    </script>

<body>
<span id="pageTitle">${label['ALFRESCO_DOCUMENT']}</span>

<div id="uploaddoc">

</div>
</body>
<span id="footerButtons" style="vertical-align: bottom;"></span>
```

I am using above code . But still while loading page its asking for username and password. Please help me

Answer (score 1):

First of all, don't use an iFrames for a simple webscript. You're not loading an entire new page which should have his own session.

Just use Client-Side JavaScript to get the JSON backend data en draw your own UI.

In any case you're compelled to use an iFrame, then just create your own myspaces webscript. Copy all the content, rename it and add your alf_ticket behind every generated url.